# Mac Catalyst build fails with "building for Mac Catalyst-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for Mac Catalyst-arm64"

Tags: macos, linker, frameworks, mac-catalyst

After updating to Xcode 12.2, my project started failing to compile because of Apple Silicon-related linking errors. I seem to have most of them fixed, but one sub-project that builds a statically-linked framework is giving me problems. And yet a sibling sub-project with apparently identical build settings doesn't.

During linking, I get this warning about the one framework:

> ld: warning: ignoring file ...Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/TCSiOSC.framework/TCSiOSC, building for Mac Catalyst-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for Mac Catalyst-arm64

I'm building on an Intel Mac, to boot (so "build active architecture only" is not a factor). I can't find any build setting that would address this problem, and a Web search turns up no hits on this exact error. Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I consulted Apple for this one, and their engineer recommended some things:

1. Turn any Swift sub-projects into Swift packages, not embedded Xcode projects. So, I deleted one library's Xcode project from the parent project, and dragged its top-level directory into the parent project to include it as a Swift package. Now... this particular sub-project (SQLite.swift) already had a Swift package defined. I haven't generated a Swift package myself before, so I can't help with that. Also, don’t forget to add it to the Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content list on the app’s target.
2. Go into your project's build settings and delete the "Supported platforms" setting. If you click on the "levels" button above the build-settings list, you can see where each setting is coming from. "Supported platforms" should be non-bold. Highlight the line and press Delete if it's bold. Then go into your target and do the same thing: delete "Supported platforms."
3. Set the Base SDK at your project (top) level to iOS; this is a must. Delete it from the target level, so it inherits from the project; I don't know if this holds true for multiple kinds of targets or all projects, but it's working for me.
4. Remove the VALID_ARCHS build setting from all targets, if it's present. That setting is deprecated.

The "build active architecture" setting doesn't make any difference after these changes in my case. The project now builds and runs under Catalyst just fine.

Comment: There is a problem with CocoaPods at the moment where *Base SDK* of the Pods project is by default set to *No SDK (MacOS)*. Changing it to *iOS* as suggested here fixed the linking problem for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: @MaxKlint does that mean the pods had a different Base SDK than the project? Where would I check for something like that?

Comment: #2 fixed the issue for me. All that you can perceive from the Xcode configuration is that it was once bold and now it is not. Wild. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and found this question. In my case, building on Debug succeeds but on Release fails. The reason is exactly the "build active architecture only" option. It is an option can be found in your PROJECT - "Build Setting" Tab then "Architectures" section. There is a setting for "Build active architecture only". By default, the Debug mode it is Yes while Release mode it is no. That caused my build to fail in release.

Comment: Thanks for that info! This wasn't the problem in my case, but you've reminded me to update this post with the solution I arrived at.

Comment: Huge thanks to [Yi Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5733005/yi-hu)!!

I had just posted a [question about this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408205/can-t-link-c-code-to-dylib-in-xcode-12-2-release-build-only) in the Apple-related “Ask Different” section.

Then I tried searching harder in the main stackoverflow and found [Yi Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5733005/yi-hu)'s answer to [Oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407700/oscar)'s .

This was **exactly** my problem and fixed it without any trouble!